# Error when plotting two words clouds in R-Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, word-cloud, wordcloud2

I'm generating separate chunks in r-markdown to generate two word clouds, but only the first cloud appears. I am using the wordcloud2 library.

Example:

```
word <- c("book", "biography", "image")
freq <- c(190, 144, 120)
freq_2018_causa <- data.frame(word, freq)

word <- c("book", "biography", "image")
freq <- c(70, 30, 15)
freq_2017_causa <- data.frame(word, freq)
```

My code in Markdown

```
{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align = "center"}
library(wordcloud2)
wordcloud2(freq_2018_causa, size = 1, color = "random-light")


{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align = "center"}
library(wordcloud2)
wordcloud2(freq_2017_causa, size = 1, color = "random-light")
```

And the error is that only a cloud is generated by markdown in html.

Comment: provide a repex examle so that we can see the actual code - you may be missing an argument in the {r,...} call at the beginning of the chunk of code!

Comment: No - add a reproducible example - with your data and code in here or an example of dummy data - we cannot comment on individual lines of code only out of context!

Comment: Sorry, I've sent you an answer unintentionally.

Comment: post all the code and the data if you want help

Comment: The data is correct and when you generate the code from the R, the clouds are generated. My problem is with Markdown.
It generates only one cloud and not two, this is my problem.

Comment: You are reassigning objects within your markdown so you are overwriting any of the early objects like word which you created earlier is over written - create separate objects, store them and then plot them - you should keep  best practise by never making objects name the same when doing something new - make a descriptive name instead like "word_1" and then "freq_1" etc

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work.